# mongoDB limit the number of entries scanned

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I'm trying mongoDB and I need translate this following SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM infos_cli 
       WHERE MATCH(denomination) AGAINST('cafe') 
       WHERE code_postal LIKE '34%'
```

My full text index definition:

```
db.infos_cli.createIndex(
    {   "code_postal": 1,
        "denomination": "text"
    }, 
    {default_language: "french"},
    {name: "indexSerch"}
)
```

And my query in mongoDb:

```
db.infos_cli.find({code_postal : /34/, $text: {$search: "cafe"}})
```

But it's not working.
Can anyone explain how I've to do ?

Comment: are you sure that code_postal is type string? - try code_postal:34

Comment: Hi, code_postal:34000 return 0 result. 
but code_postal:"34000" return some result

Comment: that's strange...  could you run db.infos_cli.find({code_postal : /34/, $text: {$search: "cafe"}}).explain() - and could you add a sample document?

Comment: the result: Error: explain failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=infos_soc.infos_cliTree: $and\n    code_postal regex /34/\n    TEXT : query=cafe, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query (if text index is compound, are equality predicates given for all prefix fields?)",
 "code" : 2
} : and some errors

Comment: - replace $text body with `{$text:{$search:"coffee",  $language: "french"} ` and let me know - other solution could be build indexes again

Comment: Error: error: {
 "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=infos_soc.infos_cliTree: TEXT : query=coffee, language=french, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query (if text index is compound, are equality predicates given for all prefix fields?)",
 "code" : 2
}

Comment: And my index:
db.infos_cli.createIndex(
 { 
 code_postal: 1,
 denomination: "text"
 }, 
 {name: "indexSerchAll"},
 {default_language: "french"}
)

Comment: drop this index and recreate without code_postal - just to see if the index makes noise or not.

Comment: If I drop the index, everything is ok. But my datatable is 5M rows. And I need sort by 2 first number on "code_postal", else it's too much slow

Answer (score 0):

In this case please create separate index for postal field and for text search

```
db.articles.createIndex({ author : 1}) //postal... in your case

db.articles.createIndex({ 
    "denomination" : "text"
}, {
    default_language : "french"
}, {
    name : "indexSerch"
})
```

> my query

```
db.getCollection('articles').find({
    $text : {
        $search : "coffee",
        $language : "french"
    }
}).explain()
```

Result shows that there is TEXT phase and IXSCAN which is desired!

> result from explain:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "testCode.articles",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$text" : {
                "$search" : "coffee",
                "$language" : "french",
                "$caseSensitive" : false,
                "$diacriticSensitive" : false
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "TEXT",
            "indexPrefix" : {},
            "indexName" : "denomination_text",
            "parsedTextQuery" : {
                "terms" : [
                    "coffe"
                ],
                "negatedTerms" : [],
                "phrases" : [],
                "negatedPhrases" : []
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "TEXT_OR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "_fts" : "text",
                            "_ftsx" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "denomination_text",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "backward",
                        "indexBounds" : {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "gbernas3-lt",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.0",
        "gitVersion" : "45d947729a0315accb6d4f15a6b06be6d9c19fe7"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

any comments welcome!